# Two switch boxes wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, receptacle

My intent is to wire two switches in a space that's split in half by a wall; I'll use a 2gang box on one side of that wall for some lights in that section. Then I'll use a single gang box on the other side offset by ~3inches or so as to not butt up against the other box BUT there's wires running down the stud I was planning on using. Can I run the wires over the outside of the junction box and let them continue downward to their receptacle?

[image: current]

[image: new]

Doesn't seem right but not sure how else to work around this??

Comment: Off the cuff the biggest problem I see is the length of wire to the box I see is the cables are not secured close enough to the box.

Comment: Well that's because I took the wire staples off for illustration of how the box might go with the wires going AROUND the box.... I don't imagine it's OK to put the staples in and then put the new box on top of the wires!

Comment: If I was doing that in conduit and steel boxes, I'd use 2-gang boxes and link them with conduit, and use the conduit to run the thru-wires through both boxes.

Comment: But it's not :)

Comment: Just a suggestion...can you move the single box to the other side of the stud? Drill a hole for the wire and mount it to the right side of the stud, offsetting the boxes. Even if it means running the wire through the stud, into the box, and back out of the box and back through the hole.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing wrong with it is you are supposed to have staples within 6 inches of the wires coming out of the box. An inspector might catch it but I personally wouldn’t worry about it. You could put a flat 2X4 (14.5” long) between the boxes to nail the wires to if you wanted.